# Input keeps repeating itself

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a vending machine and I'm slightly stuck.

code: http://pastebin.com/5AWG1qWw

In my machine I have 6 choices, but when I run the programme, everything works except when I come to the `vending=input("Select a Option: ")` so say I input "1" it will ask me the same question instead of going to `if vending==1:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would repeat after every step, since you have not done anything for the numbers between 1 and 6,

```
while error2==True:
    try:
        vending=input("Select a Option: ")
        if vending >= 7:
            print"Enter a number between 1-6. Please try again."
        elif vending==0:
            print"Enter a number between 1-6. Please try again."
            error2=False
        else:
            #do something
            # Set error2 to False to break out of the while loop.
    except NameError:
        print"Enter a number between 1-6. Please try again."
        time.sleep(1)
    except SyntaxError:
        print"Enter a number between 1-6. Please try again."
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You still don't set `error2 = False` to break out of the original `while` loop. And why would you throw a similar error in the range 1-6 too? You would like to do something else and break out of the original while loop.

Comment: Thanks dude. after the elif vending >=7: i put else: error2=false and it works now.

Comment: Nope, after whatever you do in the `else` statement I added, I show it through comments in the above code.

Comment: Yup that should work, also, in `while error2==True`, you could do, `while error2`, more readable and works the same.

Comment: oh yeah because I've already defined what errorX is. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

After inputting a number 1-6, you never set `error2` to false.  It's only set to false after inputting a `0`

Addendum:
I don't like to use variables as such simply for tracking a while loop. Alternatively you could just do

```
while True: 
    if vending = what_you_want:
        do_something()
    #then  to quit looping: 
    elif vending == 0:
        break
```